# Why does Typescript with strictNullChecks enabled ignores null checks on React's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the following example:

```
interface AppState {
    text: string | null;
}

interface ChildProps {
    text: string;
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
    state = {
        text: null
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ text: "rendered!" });
        }, 5000);
    }
    render() {
        return this.state.text !== null ? (
            <Child text={this.state.text} />
        ) : (
            "loading..."
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps> {
    render() {
        const { text } = this.props;
        return <div>{text}</div>;
    }
}
```

An error arises under `<Child text={this.state.text} />`:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

[image: typescript error even with a null check]

This does not make sense since there's an explicit null check prior to its render.

Why when extracting `text` from state, the error goes away?

```
render() {
        const { text } = this.state;
        return text !== null ? (
            <Child text={text} />
        ) : (
            "loading..."
        );
    }
```

A working example with the error enabled, replace the code in order to see it fixed:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-g15mw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you initialize state as class property, you need declare its type definition. otherwise typescript assumes you override its type that inherits from `React.Component<{}, AppState>`, and its type becomes `{ text: null }`

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
    state: AppsState = {
        text: null
    };
}
```

or just initialize state in constructor

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            text: null
        }
    }
}
```

---

as for extracting

```
// typeof this.state === { test: null }
const { text } = this.state;

if (this.state.text !== null) {
    // typeof this.state.text is still null
}

if (text !== null) {
    // typeof text is never here
    // since never is subtype of all types
    // text can be assigned to any variable
}
```

see more at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
It seems like it falls under the context of an impossible type:
since text can only be null when `state` is inferred as `{text: null}` and we explicitly pass a conditional that happens when it's not - it automatically casts it into `never`.
For more information: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-0-the-never-type#variables-with-impossible-types

The only question remains is why TS allows the extension of the type when it's a class property? You still need to initiate `text`, however you can always add more keys to it.